# How to migrate eclipse project to atmel-studio?

Tags: eclipse, atmelstudio

I want to migrate the project in atmel-studio from eclipse cdt, as I started working on an embedded c/c++ project I understood that atmel-ice is not debugging properly in eclipse it's just helping me to flash firmware nothing more than that. So, Want to migrate my whole project to atmel-studio. So, I could debug it. Looking for help thanks.

Comment: While moving away from Eclipse is perfectly understandable for countless reasons, you could also consider getting a better in-circuit debugger. As far as I know the cheap Atmel ones only work with Atmel studio and that's the root of the problem.

Comment: Anyway, migrating an embedded project from one tool chain to another is a rather big and broad topic, not sure if this site is the best place to ask.

Comment: @Lundin I can't buy another one now, is there any other way to do debugging. I found out that by using .elf I can debug in atmel-studio but need to find the symbol addresses. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an option, look into the atmel-studio capability of debugging an externally produced elf.   The tools I've used (keil, tensilica, IAR) all had ways to make a project that could debug an elf file produced externally.   You may lose some magic like source parsing/intellisense or whatever, but I've found source line debugging works just fine.

I've never used Atmel Studio, but in searching the web, I found:

1. http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/atmel-42167-atmel-studio_user%20guide.pdf
2. http://atmel-studio-doc.s3-website-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/webhelp/GUID-ECD8A826-B1DA-44FC-BE0B-5A53418A47BD-en-US-5/index.html?GUID-4C53CCC3-659D-4030-A7FD-566B19C87747

Both of which say "File->Open Object file for debugging"